# In a page content section webpart how will i insert a html table with an image background?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, css, html

I have been taking few classes and checking in console using f12 but that is not working when i am applying in the code and saving the page content section. What am i doing wrong or is there any webpart needed for it?

Comment: Have you searched Google for HTML Table Background Image?

Comment: Yes its...  background-image:url("xyz.jpg"); !!!! Though this is showing when i am testing in console but getting vanished when i am applying code and saving.

Comment: Then you problem has nothing to do with how to insert an image background. You don't know how to apply CSS in a SharePoint page; search for that

Comment: Dude i have tried taking div, possible classes inline statements nothing is working . is it because its a page content section and i aint using any webpart or something else which is restricting the things here. In the current page layout that only a page content section where i want my code to get implemented.

Comment: I figured it out , its because i was putting the code directly and not using script editor there.

Comment: You only learn from your mistakes.

Comment: Yes true, Thanks . But are you seriously answering anything here or just motivating guys here?? :D

Comment: I motivate in comments and write answers in [answers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/32871/danny-365csi-engelman?tab=answers)

Comment: Great sir !!!!!